# Simple java fish in a pond nested loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

The following piece of code gives me one very long line of fish:

```
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< (....up to 43 fish )


{
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
 { 

 for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
 { 
    if ( (i*10+j) < 43) 
    {
    System.out.print(" <#><");
    }

    else{
    System.out.print("     ");

   }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the fish to a 10 by 10 field so it looks more like this:

```
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
<#>< <#>< <#>< <#><
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<43; i++)
{ 
    if (i > 0 && i%10 == 0) 
        System.out.println();
    System.out.print(" <#><");
}
```

`i % 10` is a modulo operation. It divides `i` with `10` and returns the rest of the division. Example: if `i` is `17` then then result would be `7` because `17 / 10 = 1` with rest `7`. That the rest is `0` only happens if `i`  is `0,10,20,30,40`.

and `i > 0` is an extra check to prevent printing an extra line right from the start of your loop when `i` is still `0` and `0 / 10 = rest 0`

(you can put multiple conditions together with `&&` if **all** of them have to be `true`. 
you can put multiple conditions together with `||` if **one** of them has to be `true`. )

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what (i > 0 && i%10 == 0 ) is exactly but it works!

Comment: See my edit for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `System.out.println();` at the end of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the System.out.println . println refers to print line. after printing something cursor moves to the next line.

```
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { 
      for (int j=0; j<10; j++) { 
          if ( (i*10+j) < 43)  {
             System.out.print(" <#><");
          }
          else {
             System.out.println("     ");
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
public class hi {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i=0;
        while (i<43){

              for (int j=0 ; j<10 ; j++){

               System.out.print(" <#><");

               }
              System.out.println();
              i++;
             }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same code the following modification will result to expected output.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{ 
 for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
 { 
    if ( (i*10+j) < 43) 
    {
       System.out.print(" <#><");
    }

    else
    {
       System.exit(0);//if fishes exceeds 47 Exit
    }
 }
 System.out.println();//for new line after 10 fishes
}
```